# How to remove unused dependencies from composer?

Tags: php, composer-php

I installed a package with composer, and it installed many other packages as dependencies.

Now I uninstalled the main package with `composer remove packageauthor/packagename`, but all the old dependencies were not removed. I expected composer to clean up and only keep packages that are required according to `composer.json` and their dependencies.

How can I force composer to clean up and remove all unused packages ?

Answer (score 475, accepted):

The right way to do this is:

```
composer remove jenssegers/mongodb --update-with-dependencies
```

I must admit the flag here is not quite obvious as to what it will do.

### Update

```
composer remove jenssegers/mongodb
```

As of [v1.0.0-beta2](https://github.com/composer/composer/commit/eae6d8017a32bccb20ba00148f9d454bde80a78f) `--update-with-dependencies` is the default and is no longer required.

Comment: thanks to @Yehosef for starting the issue on github where a solution was provided, but since he did not update his answer I decided to write my own for everyones convenience

Comment: One thing to note: If you've already `composer remove …`'d, but forgot the `--update-with-dependencies` until you stumble across this question — subsequent calls to `composer remove` won't kill all dependencies. 

You'll need to revert, composer `install`, then `composer remove --update-with-dependencies `

Comment: Now I get the following message: `You are using the deprecated option "update-with-dependencies". This is now default behaviour. The --no-update-with-dependencies option can be used to remove a package without its dependencies`

Comment: **How about cleanup after the removal of a package?** -- That's where @LorenzMeyer answer goes in: ``composer update`` Thumbs up to this answer to @LorenzMeyer

Comment: This is not the answer to the question. This answers "how to remove a package".

`composer update` also doesn't work perfectly because it will upgrade some packages on the way.

`rm -rf vendor && composer install` is the valid answer.

Answer (score 37):

In fact, it is very easy.

```
composer update
```

will do all this for you, but it will also update the other packages.

To remove a package without updating the others, specifiy that package in the command, for instance:

```
composer update monolog/monolog
```

will remove the `monolog/monolog` package.

Nevertheless, there may remain some empty folders or files that cannot be removed automatically, and that have to be removed manually.

Comment: the unfortunate part about this is that it forces you to update your packages instead of just removing old versions.  Eg, If I have two packages AAA/aaa ~1 and version BBB/bbb ~2 and I am currently at version 1.0 of AAA/aaa and they released 1.1, then when I delete BBB/bbb I am automatically updated (which may not be what I was intending to do..)

Comment: You are right. If you have a better solution, come back and post it as an answer.

Comment: I don't yet - I just want to point out for others a pitfall of this approach.

Comment: it really should be an flag on the composer install .. something like `--prune`

Comment: if you like the idea  you can vote on it - https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/3751

Comment: @yehosef it looks like you got the correct answer over there. Did you?

Comment: I replied - I don't think their suggesting is viable.

Comment: Is it possible to tell `composer update` to keep unused dependencies inside the vendor directory? I do not want them to be removed, even if they are not referenced in `composer.json` anymore...

Comment: @Yehosef you're doing `update` basically asking for the updates, you can always do `composer install` and it will delete the non used packages without updating

Answer (score 35):

following commands will do the same perfectly

```
rm -rf vendor

composer install
```

Comment: This seems to be the cleanest option. Delete the vendors directory and let Composer pull everything fresh.

Comment: this is npm "save my day" style ;)

Comment: `composer install` will automatically delete unused packages

Answer (score 15):

Just run `composer install` - it will make your `vendor` directory reflect dependencies in `composer.lock` file.

In other words - it will delete any vendor which is missing in `composer.lock`.

Please update the composer itself before running this.