# Composer: remove a package, clean up dependencies, don't update other packages

Tags: php, composer-php

### The situation

Let's say I have a project with two packages installed by Composer:

```
php composer.phar require 'squizlabs/php_codesniffer:~2.0' 'phpmd/phpmd:~2.1'
```

The autogenerated `composer.json` file looks like this:

```
{
    "require": {
        "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "~2.0",
        "phpmd/phpmd": "~2.1"
    }
}
```

In the autogenerated `composer.lock` file, there are the two requested packages:

- `2.0.0 squizlabs/php_codesniffer`
- `2.1.3 phpmd/phpmd`

and also four dependencies of `phpmd/phpmd`:

- `2.0.4 pdepend/pdepend`
- `2.5.9 symfony/config`
- `2.5.9 symfony/dependency-injection`
- `2.5.9 symfony/filesystem`

A few days later, `squizlabs/php_codesniffer` version `2.1.0` is released, but I don't want
to run `update` yet. I want to stay on version `2.0.0` for now, and maybe I'll run `update` in a few days.

---

### The question

I now want to remove `phpmd/phpmd` from my project. I want to achieve the following points:

1. Delete `phpmd/phpmd` from `composer.json`
2. Delete `phpmd/phpmd` from `composer.lock`
3. Delete `phpmd/phpmd` from the `vendor` folder
4. Delete all the dependencies of `phpmd/phpmd` from `composer.lock`
5. Delete all the dependencies of `phpmd/phpmd` from the `vendor` folder
6. Do not update `squizlabs/php_codesniffer` to version `2.1.0`

*Edit:* I'd prefer a solution which doesn't require changing the
version constraint of `squizlabs/php_codesniffer` in `composer.json`

---

### What I've tried

If I run:

```
php composer.phar remove phpmd/phpmd
```

this achieves points **1, 2, 3, 6**, but does not achieve points **4, 5**.

The dependencies of `phpmd/phpmd` remain in `composer.lock` and the `vendor` folder.

If I run:

```
php composer.phar remove phpmd/phpmd
php composer.phar update
```

this achieves points **1, 2, 3, 4, 5**, but does not achieve point **6**.

`squizlabs/php_codesniffer` gets updated to version `2.1.0`.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26930816/how-to-remove-unused-dependencies-from-composer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove unused dependencies from composer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26930816/how-to-remove-unused-dependencies-from-composer)

Answer (score 66):

Remove the entry from `composer.json` then run `composer update phpmd/phpmd`.

As to why that is the solution that works. I have no idea but that is what is required to remove a package totally from `composer.lock` and `/vendor` and allow you to install a new/replacement/conflicting package.

Comment: Ty a lot , it seems composer is full of hacks, sometimes id doesn't let me upgradem but lets remove+install. In mu case your cure works like a charm

Comment: could you set this answer as solution?

Comment: Is not any kind of hack. "composer update" updates the lock according to the set json then installs the packages etc. The fact that you specify a package means that only that package will be modified in lock. This is actually a basic usage and specified in docs (https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md).

Answer (score 18):

Do this:

```
php composer.phar remove phpmd/phpmd
```

Modify the composer.json file so it contains the following require section.

```
{
    "require": {
        "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "2.0.*",
    }
}
```

Now run `composer.phar update`. That should get you where you want to be.

**Note:** You could also pin the php_codesniffer package to a specific version e.g. `2.0.0`. More information about how composer does versioning can be found on [here](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#package-versions).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This does indeed achieve what I want. However, if possible, I'd prefer a solution which doesn't require changing the version constraint of `squizlabs/php_codesniffer` in `composer.json`. Sorry, I should have made this clear in my question. Ideally, I'm looking for something similar to MacPorts' `--follow-dependencies` flag for its [`uninstall`](https://guide.macports.org/chunked/using.html#using.port.uninstall) command: "Uninstall ports that were automatically installed as dependencies of the removed port and are no longer needed".

Comment: Theres a --update-with-dependencies flag. Maybe this is what you are looking for

Answer (score 7):

To remove package from .json and .lock files you have to remove package as follows:

```
composer remove package-name
```

Comment: The question explicitly specified that this does not lead to the desired behavior. Could you elaborate why you think this does work?

Comment: This solution works fine for me - Laravel 6.0. No need to remove anything else from the json file nor the lock file.

Comment: apparently there was a bug in composer where `composer remove` was broken. Updating composer might help.

Answer (score 5):

I found this answer [here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/remove-package-using-composer-remove),

1. Manually remove the package from composer.json.
2. Manually delete vendor folder.
3. Run `composer install` (from inside your project folder).

Composer re-installs the packages listed in composer.json.

Comment: If you also remove the packages from composer.lock then this works. For me anyway.

Comment: Can you explain how that could work nowadays? `composer install` would use the lock file and reinstall the remove package

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe this to currently be possible. This is the sort of thing that you may wish to [submit as a feature request](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/new) to Composer.

Meanwhile, I think your best bet is to go with option #1: `php composer.phar remove phpmd/phpmd`

It will remove the package from your explicit dependencies without forcing you to update anything. The obsolete dependencies from your removed library will remain until you next run `composer update`, which is something you should be doing periodically anyway. Most of the files from the old dependencies should be set to autoload one way or another, so you shouldn't have any real penalties for keeping those files around other than the space they use on disk.