# Composer dependency being called after removal, forced cache clear and fresh checkout

Tags: php, wordpress, symfony, caching, composer-php

I installed the [EkinoWordpressBundle](https://github.com/ekino/EkinoWordpressBundle) and later removed it as, I believe, I no longer need it.

When I access my application I get this error:

> Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ClassNotFoundException: Attempted to
>   load class "WordpressResponseSubscriber" from namespace
>   "Ekino\WordpressBundle\Event\Subscriber". Did you forget a "use"
>   statement for another namespace? in
>   /private/var/www/cache/prod/classes.php on line 1950

When I delete `classes.php` manually I then get this error:

> Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ClassNotFoundException: Attempted to
>   load class "WordpressResponseSubscriber" from namespace
>   "Ekino\WordpressBundle\Event\Subscriber". Did you forget a "use"
>   statement for another namespace? in
>   /Library/WebServer/Documents/crmpicco/symfony/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/ContainerAwareEventDispatcher.php
>   on line 152

I have a Wordpress app and a Symfony app sitting alongside each other, which was working until I started to strip out references to the EkinoWordpressBundle. See [my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46153327/symfony-and-wordpress-sitting-alongside-each-other-in-webroot) for some background.

Why is this `WordpressResponseSubscriber` being referenced after I have removed it from my application first with composer and then with a fresh checkout?

Comment: `grep -R 'WordpressResponseSubscriber'` may be of use

Comment: @crmpicco Can you share your composer file? Or at least the portion which has your dependencies?

Comment: @PhiloEpisteme Sure, here it is https://gist.github.com/crmpicco/a6cc64c4cae9384d51ff38d5738a4a09

Comment: Did some more searching. Checked the source for the `ContainerAwareEventDispatcher`. Looks like the line in question is calling `foreach ($class::getSubscribedEvents() as $eventName => $params) {`. My guess is that you are passing in `WordpressResponseSubscriber` as an argument to the function `ContainerAwareEventDispatcher:: addSubscriberService`. What do you get when you grep for that class as suggested above? Or perhaps grep for `addSubscriberService` to see where you are using that?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there was some dependency issue with `EkinoWordpressBundle`. You may have luck if you attempt to do the following

1. Remove the offending dependency from `composer.json`
2. Run `composer update EkinoWordpressBundle`

The above was sourced from a similar question and an answer by kzpap

[Composer: remove a package, clean up dependencies, don't update other packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27944795/composer-remove-a-package-clean-up-dependencies-dont-update-other-packages)

You may want to run it first with the `--dry-run` flag to see what changes it will make.

Also note, if you are using composer < 1.0.0-beta2. Check out the changelog [here](https://github.com/composer/composer/releases/tag/1.0.0-beta2). If you do have an older version of composer you should be able to use the `--update-with-dependencies` flag.

What the above command does is update `EkinoWordPressBundle` as well as things which are dependent on it. This includes files found in the `vendor` directory. In your case, the update is to remove it.

If you continue to experience issues with `classes.php` you may alternatively try to remove composer's caches.

```
composer clear-cache
```

Keep in mind that running the above may have obvious initial performance issues because composer will not have the cache to operate off of.

Checkout the composer docs on clear-cache etc.

Of course, it is possible that you may have non-composer managed classes which depend in the removed dependency, these will have to be removed by you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have removed the bundle from composer.json and ran composer update on the bundle. I am on the latest composer. I have tried clearing composers cache with the command you provided, but the reference reappears. It's hard to see where this call is coming from considering I checked out a fresh copy of the code.

Comment: @crmpicco And if you just delete the whole vendor folder and reinstall with `composer install` ?

Comment: @Pete Yes, that's what I effectively done with a fresh checkout.