# How to determine unused packages in a composer project after removing dependencies in composer.json?

Tags: php, composer-php

We have a project that uses composer for dependency management; its `composer.json` is externally changed by a versioning tool of our own concoction, which does not keep a history of when and what was `require`'d to be able to roll back using `composer remove`. But it does roll back the `composer.json` file entirely.

When we update the `composer.json` file, we'd like to purge the now-unused packages from the project. We couldn't find a command that does just this. We have a few ideas but each with its shortcomings:

1. Delete `vendor/`, `composer.lock` and run `composer install`. Problems: very slow; only works without plugins (otherwise more than `vendor` for destination and `composer.lock` for state might be involved); versions will be reset
2. Use a combination of `composer show` and `composer why` to determine unused packages and run `compose remove` on them. This is what I expected to find implemented in an internal command since it's so obvious. Implementing externally presents a few challenges though: only text output of `composer show`, no `--format=json` or something, difficult to parse especially since it's also plagued with warning messages if any, that can't be suppressed (`-q` turns off output completely, even for commands that list things, very useless and weird IMHO).

Note: we are also using `wikimedia/composer-merge-plugin` to merge a bunch of json configs so we can't easily diff the old and new `composer.json` files to get a list of packages to be `remove`'d, we need to operate on the merged package list which only `composer` knows and will mercifully let us glimpse at via `show`.

Which is the path of least pain to achieve this?

About using `update`: we can't use it, because it would make for the following workcycle: someone removes a dependency in a module, the module gets tested against trunk and passed QA (about 3 days), then they publish their changes; then, in order to remove their dead overhead, I have to run update on everything, which updates everything to whatever random version composer may decide, and in turn means triggering testing and QA for everything (about 1 week). This workflow is completely unacceptable.

I just want to remove dead code. Removing dead code should not mean restarting the whole testing cycle.

Comment: If appropriate version constraints were set in your `composer.json`, why not go with the first way? "Very slow" does mean what exactly? How often should this be performed?

Comment: For the second way: what do you mean by "unused packages"? There should not be any installed packages that are neither listed in `composer.json` directly nor required through dependencies

Comment: @Nico Hasse : For the first point, it's bothersome enough that we do need to worry about. The fact that a still-required package can change through this operation is also something to mind about that we can't assess the consequences of right now. For the second way: `composer` has no other way of removing a package except via `remove`. The `composer.json` file(s) can be updated by a plethora of methods, including by hand or using our versioning tools. So it may occur that a package is present in `vendor` and `composer.lock` and any other place via plugins but is not in `composer.json` anymore.

Comment: If you remove both `vendor` and `composer.lock`, there is no information to determine that the version has changed. If you care about keeping the current versions, check your `composer.json` - it should hold the proper versioning information. If it doesn't, don't blame the tool, but your processes. And if you use the recommended way of removing a package, all packages required only by the removed package will also be removed

Comment: @Nico Hasse - thanks, but I don't find stating the obvious and "don't do what you need to do" a constructive reply. It's like saying "If you don't use glue, you also won't glue your fingers". Thanks, but I'd rather use glue and not glue my fingers, at the same time, it's been known to work that way.

Comment: Sorry, but then I got you wrong. You run some internal tooling that does magic with `composer.json`, it gets totally overblown this way (whatever that means - how long is that file? How often do you want to perform housekeeping?) - so far correct? Then how should Composer determine which packages from `composer.json` are needed in the first place? If removing the items from `composer.json` is done manually, does `composer update --lock` help?

Comment: @Nico Hasse - I'm just looking for a way to get a list of packages that are not required anymore - just like `composer remove` checks for just one package at a time. It's not a Quixotic quest, I hope; `composer update --lock` does not seem to remove anything, it just updates and piles up, unfortunately. It also updates the versions, which is not what I intend, at all.

Comment: Then what do you mean by „no longer required“? If a package is no longer required directly in the JSON and not required by a dependency, it is no longer listed in the lock file - or did you encounter something different?

Comment: @Nico Hasse - Do note, every PHP GUI I know of provides a `composer.json` editor and parser of sorts. So editing/changing the `composer.json` file without going through the `composer` CLI is not an "overblow" by any standard. It's the way is't actually supposed to work, by and large. If this doesn't resonate with you, it's no matter, but opinionated criticism should remain that.

Comment: @Nico Hasse - If you remove the `require` from the `composer.json` it doesn't automagically disappear from `vendor`, `composer.lock` or any other location mandated by plugins. It remains there until a `composer remove` command is issued.

Comment: Sorry for being picky some hours ago, but I usually like to get to the core of such questions. I think I understood your need now, and I'll try to work out something....

Comment: So, that was easy: have a look at https://github.com/NicoHaase/find-composer-orphans

Comment: @Nico Hasse : Thaks, but that script tries it exactly the way I stated we can't do, starting from `composer.json`: *we are also using "wikimedia/composer-merge-plugin to merge a bunch of json configs so we can't easily diff the old and new composer.json files to get a list of packages to be remove'd, we need to operate on the merged package list which only composer knows and will mercifully let us glimpse at via show."* (question text)

Comment: I have no clue what this plugin does, but maybe you should share some examples? To me, all this sounds so custom-made that I don’t know how to help. Why use such a plugin instead of simple depending packages that you could use with built-in and supported features of Composer?

Comment: @Nico Haase We have source building, data synchronisation, data migration and backup all built-in. So " simple depending packages that you could use" would mean switching the whole build system to composer's plugins systems and developing over composer a large infrastructure which is already done and working. On the other hand, getting into composer and adding a "purge" command would probably take less than a few hours. Composer is great for installing 3rd party dependencies, but my kitchen is 10 years old :) I cant' save a day's work with 3 months of banging head in walls.

Answer (score 1):

I would just run `composer update`.

If a package is no longer declared in your `composer.json` (or one of its dependencies), it will get removed when you execute `update`

Yes, it does have the side-effect of updating your dependencies to the most recent version available according to your constraints; but if your constraints are tight enough (and you can tighten them more if this kind of thing it's concern for your project) it shouldn't be problematic.

Seems less hassle than building a specific tool/work-flow for this use-case, IMO.

The main problem seems to be that your team is  removing dependencies form the project and not keeping track of those removals. Any other solution after the fact obviates that, which is the real problem.

By keeping track of the changes you could have a task that removed (`composer remove`) these files without any side-effects or additional work.

Comment: I understand your way of thinking, but you have to imagine the workcycle: someone removes a dependency in a module, the module gets tested against trunk and passed QA (about 3 days), then they publish their changes; then, in order to remove their dead overhead, I have to run `update` on everything, which updates everything to whatever random version composer may decide, and in turn means triggering testing and QA for everything (about 1 week). This workflow is completely unacceptable. I just want to remove dead code. Removing deadcode should not mean restarting the whole development cycle.

Comment: The problem is introduced because of the specifics of your deployment cycle, which seem rather unusual. These days, deployments usually mean recreating the whole thing from scratch to have immutable images for discrete versions. And it doesn't take long. An `update` takes even less. If it's "unacceptable" for your team, you'll probably have to develop your own custom solution. It wont be trivial, since you'll have to deal with the problem of recursive/concurrent/conflicting dependencies, which is what composer does for us.

Comment: But the problem is fairly unique to your setup. Most other setups are well served by `update` or `install` for this kind of scenario.

Comment: I beg to differ, I just found also this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27944795/composer-remove-a-package-clean-up-dependencies-dont-update-other-packages/37715903#37715903 . Now, saying most of the people don't need spacesuits so neither should I is not a very constructive answer :)

Answer (score 0):

So, just supposing you want to keep the existing structure (which, in my opinion, might solve your requirements well, but also brings problems), you could try to implement a Composer plugin on your own. Using the event `Composer\Installer\POST_DEPENDENCIES_SOLVING`, you might be able to access both the resolved list of dependencies and the list of packages in `composer.lock`.

Defining it could be as simple as writing such a class:

```
<?php

class ComposerDependencyHelper
{
    public static function postDependencies(\Composer\Installer\InstallerEvent $event)
    {
        $composer = $event->getComposer();
    }
}
```

And it is called in your root `composer.json` throught the script section:

```
"post-dependencies-solving": [
            "ComposerDependencyHelper::postDependencies"
        ]
```

I don't have the time to check this further, but through that `$composer` object, you should have access to a lot of information (see https://getcomposer.org/apidoc/1.6.2/Composer/Composer.html for the current documentation):

- `getPackage` returns your current package (as defined in `composer.json`), while `getPackage()->getRequires()` lists the dependencies
- `getLockedRepository` might return the list of packages currently present in `composer.lock`

Through a simple marking process (build a list of "valid" installed packages, diff this list against the package list in the repository), you could identify those dependencies that are no longer required.

To keep this whole thing more clean in the future, you should stop removing packages from `composer.json` without running `composer remove $package`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look; I have a feeling post-dependency-solving is only called by update which should do the resolving (and install if no lock file). I need to avoid that, so probably I'll need to take a look at how `show` and `why` work, there's the goldmine: the packages in `show` with no `why` are good to go.

Comment: In my tests leading to the given code, this event was also called when using `install` while an up-to-date lock file exists

Comment: And if you are fine with the output of `composer show` (as this contains all packages required through that merge plugin), pipe it to a file and use it as the input for the algorithm sketched at https://github.com/NicoHaase/find-composer-orphans)

Comment: I can't diff show to the json files: composer.json is incomplete and composer.lock is basically the same with show :)

Comment: What does `composer show` output? **All** packages that are currently required, or only those packages listed in `composer.json` (without the merged ones)?

Comment: All the packages installed.

Comment: All installed (including those you want to get rid of) or all required?

Comment: Yes, including the ones to get rid of.