# Remove unused package file

Tags: php, dependencies, composer-php

I create a `PHP` web app that need number of dependencies. It uses `Composer` to handle it. Each dependency have many unused files such as tests files, doc, extra files etc that will not being used in production environment of my app. So how do I remove those files efficiently ? I need to do it for save disk space. For now I just go thru each package folder and delete it manually. Is there any such tool I can use ? thanks.

Comment: Harddisks are cheap, programmers are expensive.

Comment: Maybe this could help a bit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26930816/how-to-remove-unused-dependencies-from-composer

Comment: Also make sure you backup your files before any removal :)

Comment: Here https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/1750 was the discussion about excluding specific directories in composer. A lot of people have that issue, but I think this is not the role of the composer. "Composer is a tool for dependency management in PHP" you can read on its documentation page. Composer it is not a build system. It cannot and won't do things that are specific to build systems like maven, ant, rake, make or phing. If you are a PHP developer you can try **phing** which I was personally using. Or try some other one.